# Where should data be transformed for the database?

Tags: forms, validation, architecture, software-design, mern

Where should data be transformed for the database? I believe this is called data normalization/sanitization.

In my database I have user created shops- like an Etsy. Let's say a user inputs a price for an item in their shop as "1,000.00". But my database stores the prices as an integer/pennies- "100000". Where should "1,000.00" be converted to "100000"?

These are the two ways I thought of.

1. **In the frontend**: The input data is converted from "1,000.00" to "100000" in the frontend before the HTTP request. In this case, the backend would validate that the price it is an integer.
2. **In the backend**: "1,000.00" is sent to the backend as is, then the backend validates that it is a price format, then the backend converts the price to an integer "100000" before being stored in the database.

It seems either would work but is one way better than the other or is there a standard way? I would think the second way is best to reduce code duplication since there is likely to be multiple frontends - mobile, web, etc- and one backend. But the first way also seems cleaner- just send what the api needs.

I'm working with a MERN application if that makes any difference, but I would think this would be language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short version

Both ways would work and I think there is no standard way. I prefer formatting in the frontend.

---

### Long version

What I do in such cases is to look at my expected business requirements and make a list of pros and cons. Here are just a few thoughts about this.

1. In case, you decide for doing every transformation of the price (formatting, normalization, sanitization) in the frontend, your backend will stay smaller and you will have less endpoints or endpoints with less options. Depending on the frontend, you can choose the perfect fit for you end user. The amount of code which is delivered will stay smaller, because the application can be cached and makes all the formatting stuff.
2. If you implement everything in the backend, you have full control about which format is delivered to your users. Especially when dealing with a lot of different languages, it could be helpful to get the correct display value directly from the server.

Furthermore, it can be helpful to take a look at some different APIs of well-known providers and how these handle prices.

The **Paypal** API uses an amount object to transfer prices as decimals together with a currency code.

```
"amount": {
    "value": "9.87",
    "currency": "USD"
}
```

It's up to you how to handle it in the frontend. Here is a link with an example request from the docs:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1#payouts_post

**Stripe** uses a slightly different model.

```
{
     unit_amount: 1600,
     currency: 'usd',
}
```

It has integer values in the base unit of the currency as the amount and a currency code to describe prices. Here are two examples to make it more clear:

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create?lang=node
- https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

In both cases, the normalization and sanitization has to be done before making requests. The response will also need formatting before showing it to the user. Of course, most of these requests are done by backend code. But if you look at the prebuilt checkout pages from Stripe or Paypal, these are also using normalized and sanitized values for their frontend integrations: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app

---

### Conclusion/My opinion

I would always prefer keeping the backend as simple as possible for security reasons. Less code (aka endpoints) means a smaller attack surface. More configuration possibilities means a lot more effort to make the application secure. Furthermore, you could write another (micro)service which overtakes some transformation tasks, if you have a business requirement to deliver everything perfectly formatted from the backend. Example use cases may be if you have a preference for backend code over frontend code (think about your/your team's skills), if you want to deploy a lot of different frontends and want to make sure that they all use a single source of truth for their display values or maybe if you need to fulfill regulatory requirements to know exactly what is delivered to your user.

Thank you for your question and I hope I have given you some guidance for your own decision. In the end, you will always wish you had chosen a different approach anyway... ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a mix between the two (which is a best practice, AFAIK).

The frontend has to do some kind of validation anyway, because it you don't want to wait for the backend to get the validation response. I would add the actual conversion here as well.

The validation code will be adapted to each frontend I guess, because each one has a different framework / language that it uses, so I don't necessarily see the code duplication here (the logic yes, but not the actual code). As a last resort, you can create a common validation library.

The backend should validate again the converted value sent by the frontends, just as a double check, and then store it in the database. You never know if the backend will be integrated with other components in the future and input sanitization is always a best practice.

Comment: Agreed, it's also important to remember that you can't trust anything that come from the client. Client side validation is great for reducing the pain of legitimate users, the backend validation should take care of the nefarious users.

Answer (score 1):

For sanitisation, it has to be on the back end for security reasons. Sanitisation is concerned with ensuring only certain field's values from your web form are even entertained. It's like a guest list at an exclusive club. It's concerned not just with the field (e.g. username) but also the value (e.g. bobbycat, or ); DROP TABLE users;). So it's about ensuring security of your database.

Normalisation, on the other hand, is concerned with transforming the data before storing them in the database. It's the example you brought up: 1,000 to 1000 because you are storing it as integers without decimals in the database.

Where does this code belong? I think there's no clear winner because it depends on your use case.

If it's a simple matter like making sure the value is an integer and not a string, you should offload that to the web form (I.e. the front end), since forms already have a "type" attribute to enforce these.

But imagine a more complicated scenario. Let's say you're building an app that allows users to construct a Facebook ads campaign (your app being the third party developer app, like Smartly.io). That means there will be something like 30 form fields that must be filled out before the user hits "create campaign". And the value in some form fields affect the validity of other parts of the form.

In such a situation, it might make sense to put at least some of the validation in the back end because there is a series of operations your back end needs to run (like create the Post, then create the Ad) in order to ensure validity. It wouldn't make sense for you to code those validations and normalisations in the front end.

So in short, it's a balance you'll need to strike. Offload the easy stuff to the front end, leveraging web APIs and form validations. Leave the more complex normalisation steps to the back end.

On a related note, there's a broader concept of ETL (extract, transform, load) that you'd use if you were trying to consume data from another service and then transforming it to fit the way you store info in your own database. In that case, it's usually a good idea to keep it as a repository on its own - using something like Apache Airflow to manage and visualise the cron jobs.